# TextBlob Python3 - "Neg Tag for Positive words"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk, textblob

I am testing textblob module for Positive and Negative words.
But some of the results are not good.
for example :

code :

```
from textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer
from textblob import TextBlob

message = "Fraud"
blob = TextBlob(message, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
a = (blob.sentiment)
print(a)
```

## Result

```
Sentiment(classification='pos', p_pos=0.6428571428571429, p_neg=0.3571428571428571)
```

it gives 90% correct answers but for some words it returns false result!!!

like :
    message = "like this"
    Sentiment(classification='neg', p_pos=0.4794333489299875, p_neg=0.5205666510700125)

```
message = "good habits"
Sentiment(classification='neg', p_pos=0.41318402216578204, p_neg=0.5868159778342183)
```

=====================================

```
"fraud" = pos
"like this" = neg
"good habits" = neg
```

Comment: The TextBlob naive bayes sentiment analysis tool is meant for sentences, not individual words or phrases, so you may get unpredictable results. You could try instead TextBlob's pattern analysis sentiment analysis method, which is the default, as it works simply by identifying positive and negative words.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, you are training the NaiveBayesAnalyzer rather than using an already trained classifier. I would recommend trying the default classifier, or checking out the docs on how to train and apply the NaiveBayesAnalyzer for classification.

Try this:
blob = TextBlob(message)